# Django how to modify database records by template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I want to delete the records which i select, and **run.html** will refresh, how can i do that?
Since i use function **run** in views.py to send records in database, and **run** need one parameter build which can be got by using **run.name**, so i think i need to pass "run.name" and "run.id" when i click the submit button.

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    (r'^home/$', 'views.home'),
    (r'^home/(?P<build>[^/]+)/$', 'views.run'),
    (r'^run/delete/$', 'views.runDelete')
)
```

## run.html

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="/run/delete">
<input type="submit" value="Delete" style="margin-left:149px; width:80px; height:30px">
<table border="1"; borderColor=black>
<td></td>
<td><b>Run</b></td>
    {% for run in run_list %}
        <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="var_delete" value="{{run.id}}"></td>
        <td>{{run.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </form>
```

## views.py

```
def run(request, build):   
    run_list = TestRun.objects.all().order_by('id')
    return render_to_response('run.html', {'run_list': run_list})

def runDelete(request, id, build):
    TestRun.objects.get(id=id).delete()
    run()
```

i also want to ask if i select multiple record in **run.html**, whether should i write a forloop in runDelete to delete all of them?

thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely take a look at Django [Form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Comment: thanks! But how can i get two parameters?
By using post i can get the selected checkbox list, but i have no ideal about how to get build name...

Comment: First, why you need build? I do not see it in your usage? And if it's a global parameter, add it to the url "/run/delete/<buildname>/" (take a look at {% url %} works.

And what are the two params you need? run.id and run.name? Why do not you get it from r = TestRun.objects.get(id=id) and use r.name?