# django checkbox select all

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

how can i select all checkbox when i click header checkbox?
By javascript? How?
And can i do that in easier method?
thanks:D

## run.html

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="/home/{{build}}/">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" style="margin-left:149px; width:80px; height:30px">
<input type="hidden" name="build_id" value="{{build_id}}" />
<table border="1"; style="margin-left:150px; border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:10px"; cellpadding="4" borderColor=black>
<tr bgcolor=#888888>
<td><input type="checkbox" align="center"></td>
<td><b>Run</b></td>
<td><b>Product</b></td>
</tr>

{% for run in run_list %}
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="var_delete" value="{{run.id}}"></td>
    <td><a href="/home/{{build}}/{{run.name}}">{{build}} {{run.name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{run.build.version}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Ah :) You're the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521725/django-how-to-modify-database-records-by-template :) Form Form Form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use javascript for that. This is an example using jquery...

```
$(".checkbox_delete").attr('checked', true);
```

put that in the click event of the header checkbox and add that class (checkbox_delete) to all the checkboxes you want checked.

Comment: hello~i post the new version in my answer, but it still not work, what wrong?
thank you~

Comment: if i want to use jquery, should i import or download some files?

Answer (score 1):

Check this one: you'll be able to toggle master checkbox selection as well in case you click on item checkbox:

```
$(function() {

  var masterCheckbox = $('#select_all');
  var slaveCheckboxes = $('.checkbox_delete');

  masterCheckbox.click(function() {
    slaveCheckboxes.attr('checked', masterCheckbox.attr('checked'));
  });

  slaveCheckboxes.click(function() {
      // Check all slave checkboxes selections: in case all are checked - check the master checkbox as well
      masterCheckbox.attr('checked', $.grep(slaveCheckboxes, function(e) {
          return $(e).attr('checked');
      }).length == slaveCheckboxes.length);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've no way but **Javascript**. Once the page is loaded you cannot do anything by django. A **stupid** method can be to attach a handler to the master checkbox to reload the page and set them checked by django but it's a **very very bad** idea.

If you're using some library like mootools or jquery it's easy to achieve.

As second hint, take a look at [django forms](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/), they make your life easier when working with everything near forms.

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery and write this, but it is nouse when i click 'select_all'...

## run.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#select_all').click( function() {
    $(".checkbox_delete").attr('checked', true);
  });
}
</script>

<form name="form" method="post" action="/home/{{build}}/">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" style="margin-left:149px; width:80px; height:30px">
<input type="hidden" name="build_id" value="{{build_id}}" />
<table border="1"; style="margin-left:150px; border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:10px"; cellpadding="4" borderColor=black>
<tr bgcolor=#888888>
<td><input id="select_all" type="checkbox" align="center"></td>
<td><b>Run</b></td>
<td><b>Product</b></td>
</tr>

{% for run in run_list %}
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="var_delete" value="{{run.id}}" class="checkbox_delete"></td>
    <td><a href="/home/{{build}}/{{run.name}}">{{build}} {{run.name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{run.build.version}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</form>
```