# Selecting all checkboxes in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to find an elegant solution without recourse to using JQuery or JS. Is there anyway that one can perform a select all on fields that are options in a model?

I'm not so keen to use: [django checkbox select all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545810/django-checkbox-select-all)

I've seen it hinted at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/dzdiZ9TLR5g

But never been able to find anything that would easily allow me to provide a select all directly from Django. Does anyone know if this is possible to switch on? Or is JS the only way to perform this?

I note this answer earlier: [select all rows in django_tables2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939548/select-all-rows-in-django-tables2)

But is there a way to avoid this approach because I may not know what why fields are - hence, if I have more than one field on each page - i.e. multiple names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any solution you write within Django would involve overriding widget renders to output html that included javascript/jquery anyway. I don't think there is any getting round it.

Edit: to answer your comment, the way I would personally do it is create a SlaveCheckboxWidget that could do something as simple inherit from the standard checkbox widget but change the css class name to "slave-checkbox" or similar, then have a MasterCheckboxWidget that includes a bit of jquery to select all `(".slave-checkbox")` and toggle them.

More on customising django widgets [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#customizing-widget-instances)

Comment: Thanks - do you know of any good solutions that would handle multiple fields on each form?

Answer (score 3):

Here is my easy solution with multiple Forms and multiple Fields :

```
        {% for form in formset %}

    <div>
        {% for field in form %}

        {{ field }}

        {% for check in field|slice:":1" %} 
        <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this,'{{ check.name }}')"/>
        Select All
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
```

Each checkbox of one Field has the same name - so js can work with it.
Note that all the fields of this example form are checkboxes.

JS Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function toggle(source,name) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i = 0,
        n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}
</script>
```

I extended this solution for django :
[How to implement "select all" check box in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386281/how-to-implement-select-all-check-box-in-html)